# CommandBinding in Window doesn't catch execution of command from ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, command

A quite simple and straightforward example.

I have a window. It has CommandBindings set to catch a RoutedUICommand execution.

```
<Window
   ...
   >
   <Window.CommandBinding>
       <CommandBinding 
           Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Command1}"  
           Executed="OnCommand1Executed" 
           CanExecute="OnCanCommand1Execute" 
           />
   </Window.CommandBinding>
</Window>
```

There's a UserControl hosted in the window, inside of which a ContextMenu is declared. A ContextMenu item has the Command property assigned to the same RoutedUICommand.

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Command1}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

But the menu item remains inactive (== disabled). Somehow command execution doesn't go up to the window. Maybe it's because ContextMenu is inside of a popup?

Everything works properly if I add needed CommandBinding into the ContextMenu.CommandBindings collection. But that's a terrible option to not have a place for a single 'global' CommandBinding.

How can I solve the problem in the best way?

UPD: Turns out it's not that bad. The Commands aren't bound **only at the first time** user opens the menu. If it's closed and reopened everything's fine. Still, it seems to be not desirable and a quite weird behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this still occur if you add Focus(); right after InitializeComponent(); in the windows constructor?

This sounds like WPF is having an issue finding the visual tree from the context menu.  Setting the focus to the main window might fix it.

Comment: To give credit where credit is due, I think this was the place where I first saw that workaround http://cebla5.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1B8262ED00250003!206.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=834175698

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6070771 for an alternative work-around. IMHO it's a better approach -- XAML only and doesn't depend on the side-effect of focus -- but it does have the drawback of causing a spurious "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error message in the XAML editor (just in the editor...the code still compiles and runs fine). If I could figure out a way to fix that error, I'd say the alternative was 100% preferable.

Answer (score 1):

How we can handle this issue in a user control? It seems that focus doesn't work in that context

Update : I found the solution here [How to set CommandTarget for MenuItem inside a ContextMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616206/wpf-usercontrol-and-commands-oh-my)

Seems that it's related to CommandTarget

```
<MenuItem x:Name="mnuProperties" Header="_Properties"
          Command="{x:Static localcommands:TaskCommands.ViewTaskProperties}"
          CommandTarget="{Binding PlacementTarget,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
```