# ContextMenu CommandParamater binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, contextmenu

I am trying to bind the `commandParamater` of my `ContextMenu` item to another element on the form, however no matter what I try the `commandParamater` is always `null`.

Can someone please show me how to correctly bind the `commandParamater` of my context menu item?

What I have:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}">
       <Grid>
          <Grid.ContextMenu>
              <ContextMenu>
                 <MenuItem Header="Rename Folder" 
                           Command="{Binding Path=ToggleControlVisability}" 
                          CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=FolderEditor}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FolderEditor}">
                 </MenuItem>
               </ContextMenu>
          </Grid.ContextMenu>

          <Label Content="{Binding Path=FolderName}"></Label>

          <StackPanel Name="FolderEditor" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                      Visibility="Hidden">
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FolderName}"></TextBox>
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ElementName Binding from MenuItem in ContextMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem encountered in WPF; Context menu itself is not part of the same visual tree as the control it was defined on, due to this it's not possible to use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` bindings.

I have also faced this issue recently and solution using Tag and `PlacementTarget` worked fine for me.

Here are some posts having different solutions to this problem(apart from one CodeNaked suggested) -

[How to set CommandTarget for MenuItem inside a ContextMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616206/wpf-usercontrol-and-commands-oh-my/616466)

http://www.sevensteps.com/binding-contextmenu-commands-in-wpf-to-the-controls-viewmodel.ashx

http://www.ikriv.com/blog/?p=434