# WPF ToolWindow that is not showed in taskbar block the application

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, taskbar

This is a problem that happens when you are in the follow situation:
-Have a main window in my application
-I create another window that doesn't show in task bar, and is a tool window.
-I show the second window as a dialog window (from the main window) 
-I switch to another application running in my system, and when i came back to the application the main window is showed, but it is locked by the second windows, that is not showed.

This is the code of the second window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.DialogWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DialogWindow" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ShowInTaskbar="False">
   <!--Some content-->
</Windows>
```

And this is the code that shows the second window:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogWindow = new DialogWindow();
        dialogWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

How can i solve this problem, and still showing a dialog windows that doesn't shows in task bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should set the `DialogWindow.Owner` property to the parent window. See this answer [WPF: How do I set the Owner Window of a Dialog shown by a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607370/wpf-how-do-i-set-the-owner-window-of-a-dialog-shown-by-a-usercontrol)

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialogWindow = new DialogWindow();
    dialogWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this)
    dialogWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

That should put the `DialogWindow` modally in front of its parent at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Set `TopMost=True` to the dialog window.

Comment: Yes, but this show it over all other windows, is there another way?