# Opened windows C# WPF

Tags: wpf, windows

I have this problem:

In a C# WPF application:

> 1. I open a new Window `(showOnTaskBar=true, noresize, centered);`
> 2. From this opened window I open another one that is above the other opened window. The new window is without blue top bar and
>      `showOnTaskbar=false, showDialog();`
> 3. Everything is ok but if I change the focus, I mean, for example, I open Firefox or another program and then I want to go back to my
>      opened windows I saw just the first opened window (from step 1) the
>      other modal window comes up only with `ALT+TAB.`

So, is there a way to keep both windows always displayed ?

Code to open the second window (from the first normally opened window in step 1):

```
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    formA2.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    form2.ShowDialog();
```

Thank you,
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as I think you have said you are opening the second window from the first, I'm pretty sure you want to try setting the owner of the dialog like this:

```
form2.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

See [WPF: How do I set the Owner Window of a Dialog shown by a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607370/wpf-how-do-i-set-the-owner-window-of-a-dialog-shown-by-a-usercontrol)

Hope this helps,
Jay

Comment: No problems at all, glad to help! Please can you mark this post as the accepted answer if your question has been resolved.